# "Redirect_uri is invalid" using Microsoft Oauth to sign in for accounts not in Microsoft domain

Tags: azure, oauth, single-sign-on

I have been successful setting up a web application that uses Microsoft as an OAuth2 provider server. I've done so by registering an application in the Azure cloud console. Users from the same domain as the application can now use their Microsoft account to authenticate with the web app. However, when I try to use some other accounts (for example, a hotmail account) I am unsuccessful. This is unfortunate as I am trying to make it so that any Microsoft users can use OAuth2 to sign up with my app.

For example, when I initiate the signin process, I end up at a URL like the following:

```
https://login.microsoft.com/{clientid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=email%20profile%20openid&response_mode=form_post
```

I then see a login prompt. However, when I input certain emails I end up at the following URL (removing the parameters that may reveal sensitive info):

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoft.com%2fcommon%2ffederation%2foauth2msa&state={long_state_string}&estsfed={estsfed}&uaid={uaid}&fci={fci}&username={username}&login_hint={offending_email}
```

The page then displays the following message:

> We're unable to complete your request

> invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

As you can see, I am being redirected to `https://login.microsoft.com/common/federation/oauth2msa`. I assume there is some sort of additional OAuth processes going on in the background that are causing problems.

Any help would we greatly appreciated! I haven't had any luck researching this issue on my own.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> When I try to use some other accounts (for example, a hotmail account) I am unsuccessful.

**To resolve the issue**, you have to create “Accounts in any organizational directory (*Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant*) and personal Microsoft accounts (*e.g. Skype, Xbox*)” Application like below:

[image]

This will allow the application to be able access by all the Microsoft Accounts.

I created an  **Azure AD Application**  and granted API permissions like below:

[image]

Now I used the below  **authorize**  endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=5a209dfd-d6df-4018-bfd3-xxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.io
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid profile email
&state=12345
```

I got the similar  **error**  like below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the provided URL is not matching the URL configured in the Azure Portal or Azure AD Application.

**To resolve the error**, make to check the redirect URI in the Portal like below:

[image]

And then pass the above redirect URL while authorizing the users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=5a209dfd-d6df-4018-bfd3-xxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid profile email
&state=12345
```

[image]

The user got logged in successfully after using valid redirect URI.